# Persistent highlight text on page

Tags: gratis, web-browser

I read a lot of one-page documentations, which can span many 'ordinary' pages. I want a way to highlight the bits I have read so I can quickly go on to the bits I haven't read.

For example, I would be able to select a block of text, right-click and select highlight, and it will highlight that text.

Are there any extensions for any browsers which can allow me to highlight text and save those highlights? Normally, I use Chrome on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I found [Super Simple Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio?hl=en) to be the best match. I can open it on multiple tabs and the highlighting will still sync. You can also close the browser and restart it and the highlight still persists.

However, all changes are local and highlights do not sync between browsers on the same account on different computers.